# Creating Store in GeoServer workspace using REST API?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, geoserver-rest-api

I'm building a PHP class to interact with my GeoServer. I'm following the limited [Documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html), this [GeoServer REST API with PHP](http://cnokello.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/geoserver-rest-api-with-php.html) post and also this [great advice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19194/83490). I've successfully created/deleted a Workspace.

But when I try to upload a *Shapefile* it fails because no `dataStore` endpoint exists in my *Workspace* (I get a 404 response from cURL). So, I guess I should create a *Store* before trying to upload a *Shapefile*.

I've failed at finding any information regarding this issue (both here at GIS SE or Googling) but I've successfully created a *Store* with some RevEng:

I've checked the JSON for my GeoServer's default *Store*:

```
{
  "dataStore": {
    "name": "cntry_shp",
    "type": "Directory of spatial files (shapefiles)",
    "enabled": true,
    "workspace": {
      "name": "opengeo",
      "href": "http:\/\/0.0.0.0:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/opengeo.json"
    },
    "connectionParameters": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "@key": "memory mapped buffer",
          "$": "false"
        },
        {
          "@key": "timezone",
          "$": "America\/Vancouver"
        },
        {
          "@key": "fstype",
          "$": "shape-ng"
        },
        {
          "@key": "create spatial index",
          "$": "true"
        },
        {
          "@key": "charset",
          "$": "ISO-8859-1"
        },
        {
          "@key": "filetype",
          "$": "shapefile"
        },
        {
          "@key": "cache and reuse memory maps",
          "$": "true"
        },
        {
          "@key": "enable spatial index",
          "$": "true"
        },
        {
          "@key": "url",
          "$": "file:workspaces\/opengeo\/data"
        },
        {
          "@key": "namespace",
          "$": "http:\/\/opengeo.org"
        }
      ]
    },
    "_default": false,
    "featureTypes": "http:\/\/0.0.0.0:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/opengeo\/datastores\/cntry_shp\/featuretypes.json"
  }
}
```

I copied it, replacing its name and workspace, and inserted it in my system with a cURL call at the endpoint:

```
 rest/workspaces/MY_WORKSPACE/datastores
```

Then I tried to upload a *Shapefile* to it, and it failed. Anyway, I don't think this is the right way to do this.

Do you know which is the right way or, at least, do you know some examples or documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GeoServer REST manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html) has a section on [creating DataStores](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html) that should show how its done. Basically you make a POST of the file to `/workspaces/<ws>/datastores[.<format>]`.

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -T nycDataStore.xml -H "Content-type: text/xml"
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores
```

But GeoServer will create a DataStore for you when you PUT a new ShapeFile:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip"
  --data-binary @roads.zip
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/roads/file.shp
```