# Create a parametrized SQL view based layer using geo.Geoserver Python API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, sql-view

I created "by hand" (using GeoServer HTML configuration interface) a layer based on the following SQL view:

```
SELECT p1.suid, p1.id, p1.geometry, p1.classname, p2.date, COALESCE(p2.percentage, 0) - COALESCE(p1.percentage, 0) AS percentage
FROM get_300km_percentages('%classname%', '%enddate%'::date, '%prevdate%'::date) p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN get_300km_percentages('%classname%', '%startdate%'::date, '%enddate%'::date) p2
ON p1.suid = p2.suid
ORDER BY 
    percentage %order%
LIMIT 
    %limit%
```

In the picture, we can see that all parameters, including %order% and %limit%" are ok. They were correctly guessed by the API.

[image]

How can I create a layer like that using geo.Geoserver or another Python-based GeoServer config library?

Comment: Tks, ThomasG77.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it without a dedicated GeoServer library, only using GeoServer REST in combination with `requests` library and since you already said you created the layer "by hand", then this approach should work for you.

#### 1. Find the JSON or XML definition of your layer (previously created in GeoServer UI) as instructed in the top answer here:

[Creating Layer in GeoServer using REST](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/creating-layer-in-geoserver-using-rest)

The url with layer definition in json may look like this on local GeoServer:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspace_name}/datastores/{datastore_name}/featuretypes/{layer_name}.json

What you get from this is what you should post as a body of the request later in order to create the layer via REST.

#### 2. Make the proper request

Python example:

```py
    import requests

    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = ('user', 'pass') #admin - geoserver?
    url = '<geoserver_url>/rest/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<store>/featuretypes/'
    #example 
    # 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/leo/datastores/localpai/featuretypes/'

    test = session.get(url=url)
    #check if the url works - you should get a list of featuretypes for this workspace and datastore
    # print(test.text)


    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    #JSON definition of the layer obtained in step 1.
    data = 'JSON_OBTAINED_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP_AS_STRING'
    resp = session.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(resp.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, Leon.

Comment: Did the solution help you?

Comment: Yes, it helped.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted then :)

Comment: Tks! How should I do that?

Comment: @MauroAssis There's a big check mark next to the answer.  Click that to accept