cURL to Migrate and Publish GeoPackage to GeoServer
I've been using cURL to move a GeoPackage to GeoServer (v2.22.2) with hopes to use the same command to update the GeoPackage on a schedule.  I'm seeing a couple of issues.

The GeoPackage file on the server doesn't seem to get updated when I run the command again with new data.
The Geopackage has two datasets within it (a points dataset and a lines dataset).  When I run the cURL command, only the first dataset (points) gets published.  I have to go into the GeoServer GUI and manually publish the second (line) layer

Here's what I'm using:
curl -v -u <username>:<password> -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/x-sqlite3" --data-binary @"C:\<path to geopackage>.gpkg" http://localhost:8083/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<Workspace_Name>/datastores/GeoPackages/file.gpkg

Ultimately I want to use cURL to migrate the local GPKG, update the GeoPackage data store, and publish the data within the package a layer.  Then I want to be able to run the same script again when updates are needed.
Anyone have any suggestions?

You can create a layer from the datastore after you create that

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/creating-layer-in-geoserver-using-rest

Thanks Ian.  I'm aware that I can create a layer from the GeoPackage datastore once it's been added.  My question is, why when I add the GeoPackage using cURL does only one of the two layers in the GeoPackage get published as a layer.  The second one I have to manually add through the GeoServer web GUI.

To be honest I'm surprised that it processes the first layer when you use REST. I would expect to need to add all the layers. If all you do is change the underlying file then it should just work (provided no one was using one of the layers when you added the file)

Yeah it's acts strange.  It just publishes one of the two layers that are in the GeoPackage. I also notice that if the Data Store doesn't exist prior to running the cURL command, it'll generate the data store.  However when I try to view the properties of the data store, it throws errors.  I wasn't sure if I needed to add some additional syntax to the command that would allow the second layer to be published.
